# Django staticfiles static tempalate helper equivalent in view (Python code)

Tags: django, static, asset-pipeline, django-1.9

I have a Django app which uses `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`, in production static assets are served via a CDN and references to them in templates are correctly set, e.g.

Template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'some.js' %}"></script>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/some.abc123.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to get the fully-qualified URL to a static asset in a view?
I would like to have a view that redirects to a static asset on my CDN.

Something like:

```
import django.http HttpResponseRedirect

def my_lovely_view(request):
    static_asset_url = static('some.js') # does this fn exist?
    # static_asset_url == 'https://example.com/some.abc123.js'
    return HttpResponseRedirect(static_asset_url)
```

Comment: Of course I could hardcode this but then I loose the automatic versioning provided by ManifestStaticFileStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

static_asset_url = static('x.jpg')
```

try this